# Append text file in python

Tags: python

I want to write a code which appends a file as follows:

Input file contents are:

```
a,b
c,d
```

I have another file with contents:

```
2
4
```

The contents in output file should be:

```
a,b,2
c,d,4
```

I am not able to write a code for this. Can anyone help me out with this please!!

Comment: This is not a coding or tutorial service.  Please repeat the intro tour, especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You cannot simply dump your homework here.

Comment: Open the input files, open the output file, in a loop read a line from each input file, write to the output file the first input file's line, then a comma, then the second input file's line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I agree with the first comment, I like internet points.

First, open and read the lines of all files and remove all trailing newline characters

```
a = [i.strip("\n") for i in open("fileA.txt").readlines()]
b = [i.strip("\n") for i in open("fileb.txt").readlines()]
```

Add the content from each line of *b* to *a*

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] = a[i] + "," + b[i]
```

Finnaly write to a third file

```
c = open("fileC.txt", "w") # With write permissions
for i in a:
    c.write(i)
```

Close (and save) all files

```
a.close()
b.close()
c.close()
```